# telethon error after inserting phone number

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using telethon to read messages from a specific telegram channel. I use this code to get the messages

```
import configparser
from telethon import TelegramClient

SESSION_NAME = "test_session_1"

# Reading Configs
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

# Setting configuration values
api_id = int(config['Telegram']['api_id'])
api_hash = str(config['Telegram']['api_hash'])

phone = config['Telegram']['phone']
username = config['Telegram']['username']

messages_dict = {}
channel_list = ["channelname"]

client = TelegramClient(SESSION_NAME, api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    # get last messages of the channel
    async for message in client.iter_messages(channel_list[0], limit=2):
        print(message.text)
        print()

    # You can send messages to yourself...
    #await client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!')

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The session starts and it ask me for my phone number, I insert it and I receive the code in telegram but then the program raise this exception

```
Please enter your phone (or bot token): +01XXXXXXXX
Unexpected exception in the receive loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 332, in _recv_loop
    data = await self._recv()
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 369, in _recv
    return await self._codec.read_packet(self._reader)
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\tcpfull.py", line 25, in read_packet
    packet_len_seq = await reader.readexactly(8)  # 4 and 4
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 679, in readexactly
    await self._wait_for_data('readexactly')
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 473, in _wait_for_data
    await self._waiter
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
Unhandled exception from recv_task after cancelling <class '_asyncio.Task'> (<Task finished coro=<Connection._recv_loop() done, defined at D:\Python 3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py:325> exception=UnboundLocalError("local variable 'e' referenced before assignment")>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 332, in _recv_loop
    data = await self._recv()
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 369, in _recv
    return await self._codec.read_packet(self._reader)
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\tcpfull.py", line 25, in read_packet
    packet_len_seq = await reader.readexactly(8)  # 4 and 4
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 679, in readexactly
    await self._wait_for_data('readexactly')
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 473, in _wait_for_data
    await self._waiter
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\site-packages\telethon\helpers.py", line 176, in _cancel
    await task
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 344, in _recv_loop
    await self._recv_queue.put((None, e))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
Unhandled error while receiving data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 505, in _recv_loop
    body = await self._connection.recv()
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 299, in recv
    result, err = await self._recv_queue.get()
  File "D:\Python 3\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 159, in get
    await getter
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
Please enter the code you received: XXXXX
```

I can insert the pin but after nothing happens and the program is stucked until I press ctrl+c
How can I solve this exception?

Telethon version 1.28.2

Comment: Where is this code asking for a phone number?

Comment: I run the code I posted and then the console asks me for the phone number as you can see from the log error

Comment: can you edit your question and include telethon version (from `pip show telethon`)

Comment: yes sure, added at the bottom of the question. It is the 1.28.2 @MustA

Comment: Thanks, it's a bug in the library it doesn't show you the actual error, but there was still some error in the receive loop, try delete the session file (SESSION_NAME) and relogin

Comment: yes I deleted the session file multiple times and also tried to change the name but I get the same error @MustA

Comment: "local variable 'e' referenced before assignment" is an error that should be fixed in the next version of the library (v1.28.4 and above should contain the fix).